# WebStorm debug mode doesn't hit breakpoints (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm using debugging for node.js in webstorm. Track 'server.js' file, all breakpoints inside work correctly and have [checked sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHCFu.png), but inside other files debugger skip all breakpoints and they not have [checked sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h49xG.png), how to fix this?

Comment: used you the cluster mode or not ?

Comment: not enough information to track down the issue. Sample project would be helpful. I'd suggest creating a support ticket